# Send Packets through IPERF

Tags: c, tcp

I have problem and its about using IPERF . It sends one packet at a time so to use it to fuzz IPv6 I want to send 10000 or 1000000 packets at a time.

Tell me if it is possible to send such quantity of packets if not then atleast how can i test on IPERF?

Any sugguestions?

Answer (score 0):

iperf sends packets according to TCP (or UDP) protocol. if by one packet at a time you mean waiting for ack for every packet then this is not true.

1000000 packets sent at the same time would not reach anywhere it will be a fatal collision.

iperf can receive a -P argument for number of parallel threads to open. but anyway packets will "travel" one at a time over the medium (air/ethernet cable/fiber etc.) otherwise they will collide and retransmit.